# Geometric and Arithmetic Sequence Problem

Tags: arithmetic, geometric-series

So the question goes as follows :

"An employee has a starting salary of $20,000 and can choose from two salary options.
Option 1 has a salary increased of 5% a year. Option 2 has a guaranteed increase of 1,000 dollars each year."

1. Which option is initially more beneficial?
2. Which option is more beneficial after 10 years?

So, I know that this is a problem of geometric and arithmetic sequence. For the first question, I wrote that Option 1 would be the better one financially because it is an exponential growth and naturally it will have more than a linear graph.

For the second question, I wrote again that Option 1 would be more beneficial after 10 years because inputting the 11th term as n in the equation I have, I got $20,000(1.05)^{10}$ which would be 32,578 dollars compared to Option 2's 32,000.

Is this work correct? I just want to be sure. Thanks!

Comment: `Which option is initially more beneficial?` That's ambiguous unless `initially` is better defined. Both options give the same salary for the *second* year. After that, the GP wins of course.

Comment: @dxiv Yeah, what confused me at first was how initially would be defined since I also found that they both give 21,000 dollars after the first year. I think I'll just mention that then. Thanks.

Comment: I admit I expected a catch.  That n percent of salary is initially less than fixed raise r.  But 5% of 20,000 *is* 1000.  So initially they are equal but only for the first year.  The arithmetic  is never better.

Answer (score 1):

For the second question, what you have shown is that for $n=11$, the second option is better, but you haven't shown that this holds for all $n > 11$.

To show this, notice that after $n$ years, option $1$ would give $20,000(1+0.05)^n$ dollars, while option $2$ would give $20,000(1+0.05n)$ dollars. Now we can use [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality), which shows that $(1+x)^n > 1+nx$ for all real numbers $n > 1$ and $x > -1$.

Substituting $x = 0.05$ shows that option $2$ is better for all $n > 1$.